# After setting Xamarin forms IOS part of the project as startup option project I get The "UnpackFrameworks" task failed unexpectedly error

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, unpack, hot-reload

For context I opened my other developers GitHub branch of our project in Visual Studio. As soon as I set the project start up option to iOS and tried to run it, I got the error shown below. I am plugging my phone in and I successfully went through the Hot Reload setup steps (linking developer account etc). This error does not show up when running the android project.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Details
Error       The "UnpackFrameworks" task failed unexpectedly.
System.BadImageFormatException: Format of the executable (.exe) or library (.dll) is invalid.
   at Mono.Cecil.PE.ImageReader.ReadOptionalHeaders(UInt16& subsystem, UInt16& dll_characteristics) in C:\src\cecil\Mono.Cecil.PE\ImageReader.cs:line 197
   at Mono.Cecil.PE.ImageReader.ReadImage() in C:\src\cecil\Mono.Cecil.PE\ImageReader.cs:line 86
   at Mono.Cecil.PE.ImageReader.ReadImage(Disposable`1 stream, String file_name) in C:\src\cecil\Mono.Cecil.PE\ImageReader.cs:line 765
   at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.ReadModule(String fileName, ReaderParameters parameters) in C:\src\cecil\Mono.Cecil\ModuleDefinition.cs:line 1113
   at Xamarin.iOS.HotRestart.Tasks.UnpackFrameworks.Execute() in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-macios/msbuild/Xamarin.iOS.Tasks.Windows/Tasks/UnpackHotRestartFrameworks.cs:line 35
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() StartUpz8.iOS
```

I have already tried to debug by rebuilding project, checking packages are updated, searching for the problematic files etc however nothing has worked.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/CrossGeeks/FirebasePushNotificationPlugin/issues/437) on the Github and you can try the solution by editing Xamarin.iOS.HotRestart.targets file.

Search UnpackFrameworks node and add `ContinueOnError="true"`.

```
<UnpackFrameworks ContinueOnError="true"
        ReferencedAssemblies="@(AssembliesWithFrameworks)"
        IntermediateOutputPath="$(DeviceSpecificIntermediateOutputPath)">

        <Output TaskParameter="Frameworks" ItemName="_UnpackedFramework" />
    </UnpackFrameworks>
```